# DTO - Multiple Services & Redundant DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

We follow micro-service arch for our application developed using spring-boot. To explain the problem, Lets consider 3 different services A, B, C. Some of the APIs of Service C are also consumed by Service A and B.

I have a DTO for the API in Project C (service C). My question is - for Projects A & B, should  I be creating redundant DTO classes to consume the Service C APIs? Or should I be creating a separate jar for DTOs - so that it can be reused across multiple services?

What is the approach you have followed If you had come across similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on some particular usecases.

If the `DTO` is a common class that is used in many modules of you project, It should be contained in a `common` module.

There is another solution I think that you can treat service **C** as an API service (like Google Map API for example). So when you provide a service for your clients, you should provide a library for your clients. Therefore, after you develop service **C**, you can develop a `C service library` that contains **DTO** needed for its clients.

To use API from C service, A and B need to import `C service library` and call `(new CService()).getSomething()`

Comment: I really like the idea of services providing their own client library. Just 1 question - from where can I learn such best practices? or how did you learn? Can you please guide me?

Comment: I've learn it from practice projects. In additional, I use quite lot of API, most of them provide us a library. So I think it could be a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry to bug you! Can you please share some of the sources/books/blogs/youtube tutorial/practice project which helped you? I would appreciate anything you could share.

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/spring-petclinic. This site also has a lot of resource you can learn https://www.baeldung.com

Comment: I'm just a fresher so there a lot of things I need to learn :D

Comment: nice. for me you are a senior :)

Comment: i would rather not recommend client libraries. they (often) cause unnecessary coupling between services and restrict your technology to the ones in which the lib is written.

Comment: we name `service library` as `api-client`. For example `bpm` module will provide `bpm-api-client` to be used in microservices that call API from `bpm`

Comment: @RamPrakash Take a look at [This article](https://www.vinsguru.com/microservices-architecture-how-to-share-dto-data-transfer-objects/)

Answer (score 0):

Create `common` *(for example : com.example.common)* package in your project. Then, you create a sub-package with the name `dto` *(For example : com.example.common.dto)* and put all DTOs which will be commonly used across all the services.
This approach should be taken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put them in a separate `commons` API and you can use this jar in your dependencies. This will be helpful as you can even write some interfaces (for services) or some utility classes like encryption/decryption(for auth) in this `commons` package and implement them in any of your micro services.